# Cannot disable collapse on sticky nav-bar header - (Bootstrap/CSS/JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a common nav-bar header on all of the pages on my site, and yesterday I duplicated the header.js file to look different on different pages. When I did that, 2/3 of the pages did not change but the third all of a sudden has a collapsing header. I want the sticky header but no collapsing at the top. Any advice or code to disable this function would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the JS file with the HTML:

```
document.write(
"<header class='header' id='home'>" +
"       <!-- STICKY NAVIGATION -->" +
"       <div class='navbar navbar-default nav-links navbar-fixed-top sticky-navigation'>" +
"           <div class='container'>" +
"               <div class='navbar-header'>" +

"                   <!-- LOGO ON STICKY NAV BAR -->" +
"                   <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#kane-navigation'>" +
"                   <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>" +
"                   <span class='icon-bar'></span>" +
"                   <span class='icon-bar'></span>" +
"                   <span class='icon-bar'></span>" +
"                   </button>" +

"                   <a class='navbar-brand' href='#''><img src='images/logo.png' alt=''></a>" +

"               </div>" +

"               <!-- NAVIGATION LINKS -->" +
"               <div class='navbar-collapse collapse' id='kane-navigation'>" +
"                   <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right main-navigation'>" +
"                       <li><a href=''></a></li>" +
"                       <li><a href=''></a></li>" +
"                       <li><a href=''></a></li>" +
"                       <!-- <li><a href=''></a></li> -->" +
"                       <!--<li><a href=''></a></li> -->" +
"                   </ul>" +
"               </div>" +
"           </div> <!-- /END CONTAINER -->" +
"       </div> <!-- /END STICKY NAVIGATION -->" +
"</header>"
);
```

and then it's referenced in the HTML file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/header.js"></script>
```

Comment: A link or active code in a demo would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had previously added a small list of style scripts, one being

```
<script src="js/jquery.ajaxchimp.min.js"></script>
```

which was enabling the nav-bar collapse function.